# Can't import java libraries with matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I am running a matlab function which uses the LinkedList class from java. But when I run the script I get the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'LinkedList'.

 Error in (line 6)
 Q = LinkedList();
```

In the beggining of the code I do the following

```
import java.util.LinkedList
Q = LinkedList();
```

I think matlab is not founding java library files. Java is installed on my computer as the following command on my linux machine shows:

```
update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1051 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

I am using the command line matlab.

What I missed here?

Comment: It is not enough to have the JRE on your computer.  Does you project have something that is pointing to the JRE or JDK adding it to the class path?  Are there other Java objects that are being seen?

Comment: @mad: Most matlab versions bring their own JRE. What is the output of `version -java`? Verify that this JRE-Version includes a LinkedList. Which Matlab Version are you using?

Comment: @Daniel >> version -java 
ans = Java is not enabled 
My version is matlab 2012a

Comment: @BrianC My project is not pointing anywhere, should i use javaaddpath or something?

Comment: @Daniel on my linux shell,
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: forgive me if I am wrong but don't you need the "new" keyword in java?

Comment: @Gregor In this case no.

Comment: @Gregor: Strictly speaking, the code is a matlab script calling the java interface of matlab. The syntax is slightly different, you don't declare variables and you don't use the new statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab 2012a is bundled with an Java 6 JRE. Unless you require a newer Java (which does not seem to be the case) I would strongly recommend to use this java version. To make Java available:

- Check your launcher starting Matlab in Command Line. Make sure -nojvm ist not set.
- Make sure java is executable, java is located in the matlab directory `matlab/sys/java/jre/glnxa64`
- Try using a full desktop matlab if both previous steps don't help. The desktop requires java, here you might get some useful error message.
- The error might also be cased by an invalid installation process (e.g. copying /moving matlab without setting the environment), for example the environment variable `MATLAB_JAVA` might be missing. If this is the case, reinstall matlab with the official installer.

Comment: my problem is solved because before I was calling matlab by an alias command, and in this alias -nojvm was set. Also, I had to set enviroment variable MATLAB_JAVA to the directory you suggested, by using setenv inside matlab and export outside matlab. Thank you.